# Why is deleted memory unable to be reused

Tags: c++, windows-7, dynamic-memory-allocation, allocator

I am using C++ on Windows 7 with MSVC 9.0, and have also been able to test and reproduce on Windows XP SP3 with MSVC 9.0.

If I allocate 1 GB of 0.5 MB sized objects, when I delete them, everything is ok and behaves as expected. However if I allocate 1 GB of 0.25 MB sized objects when I delete them, the memory remains reserved (yellow in [Address Space Monitor](http://hashpling.org/asm/)) and from then on will only be able to be used for allocations smaller than 0.25 MB.

This simple code will let you test both scenarios by changing which struct is typedef'd. After it has allocated and deleted the structs it will then allocate 1 GB of 1 MB char buffers to see if the char buffers will use the memory that the structs once occupied.

```
struct HalfMegStruct
{
    HalfMegStruct():m_Next(0){}

    /* return the number of objects needed to allocate one gig */
    static int getIterations(){ return 2048; }

    int m_Data[131071];
    HalfMegStruct* m_Next;
};

struct QuarterMegStruct
{
    QuarterMegStruct():m_Next(0){}

    /* return the number of objects needed to allocate one gig */
    static int getIterations(){ return 4096; }

    int m_Data[65535];
    QuarterMegStruct* m_Next;
};

// which struct to use
typedef QuarterMegStruct UseType;

int main()
{
    UseType* first = new UseType;
    UseType* current = first;

    for ( int i = 0; i < UseType::getIterations(); ++i )
        current = current->m_Next = new UseType;

    while ( first->m_Next )
    {
        UseType* temp = first->m_Next;
        delete first;
        first = temp;
    }

    delete first;

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < 1024; ++i )
        // one meg buffer, i'm aware this is a leak but its for illustrative purposes. 
        new char[ 1048576 ]; 

    return 0;
}
```

Below you can see my results from within [Address Space Monitor](http://hashpling.org/asm/). Let me stress that **the only difference between these two end results is the size of the structs being allocated up to the 1 GB marker**.

[image: Quarter Meg]
[image: Half Meg]

This seems like quite a serious problem to me, and one that many people could be suffering from and not even know it.

- So is this by design or should this be considered a bug?
- Can I make small deleted objects actually be free for use by larger allocations?
- And more out of curiosity, does a Mac or a Linux machine suffer from the same problem?

Comment: Smells like memory fragmentation, except for the size threshold.

Comment: It does, however memory fragmentation is when there is wasted space between allocated objects. in the above code, everything has been deallocated, so memory fragmentation cannot be the issue.

Comment: You say the reserved memory can only be used to allocated objects smaller than 0.25MB. So, when you allocate many larger objects, do you get an out-of-memory exception while this memory is still reserved? I ask this because, on Mac OS, the operating system will keep unused memory reserved for faster reallocation, unless another process really needs that memory.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: Yes, out-of-memory exceptions are thrown before this memory is used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I cannot positively state this is the case, but this does look like memory fragmentation (in one of its many forms). The allocator (malloc) might be keeping buckets of different sizes to enable fast allocation, after you release the memory, instead of directly giving it back to the OS it is keeping the buckets so that later allocations of the same size can be processed from the same memory. If this is the case, the memory would be available for further allocations of the same size.

This type of *optimization*, is usually disabled for *big* objects, as it requires *reserving* memory even if not in use. If the threshold is somewhere between your two sizes, that would explain the behavior.

Note that while you might see this as weird, in most programs (not test, but real life) the memory usage patterns are repeated: if you asked for 100k blocks once, it more often than not is the case that you will do it again. And keeping the memory *reserved* can improve performance and actually *reduce* fragmentation that would come from all requests being granted from the same bucket.

You can, if you want to invest some time, learn how your allocator works by analyzing the behavior. Write some tests, that will acquire size X, release it, then acquire size Y and then show the memory usage. Fix the value of X and play with Y. If the requests for both sizes are granted from the same buckets, you will not have reserved/unused memory (image on the left), while when the sizes are granted from different buckets you will see the effect on the image on the right.

I don't usually code for windows, and I don't even have Windows 7, so I cannot positively state that this is the case, but it does look like it.

Comment: I thought it would be something like this, however my understanding of allocators was that they should coalesce neighboring blocks of freed memory into larger chunks of available memory, so that it would then be available to use for larger allocations. Still this doesn't help me, as the program I found this in is loading a massive XML file that makes many small allocations in the loading process and then runs out of memory during the second loading phase which loads images and meshes (game assets) specified in the XML.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm the same behaviour with g++ 4.4.0 under Windows 7, so it's not in the compiler. In fact, the program fails when `getIterations()` returns `3590` or more -- do you get the same cutoff? This looks like a bug in Windows system memory allocation. It's all very well for knowledgeable souls to talk about memory fragmentation, but everything got deleted here, so the observed behaviour definitely shouldn't happen.

Comment: Different things are called memory fragmentation. In a naïve memory allocator that yields all requests from a single heap, memory fragmentation refers to the holes in memory that cannot be allocated as they are too small for the request. Other implementations would keep different *heaps* for different sized objects, in an attempt to reduce *fragmentation*, so that sequences of new/delete/new/delete/new with the same size are guaranteed not to fragment the memory. Memory not available because it is being hold in an different heap is also called *fragmentation* (of a different kind)

Comment: @David: Like I said, everything got deleted. The memory allocator should recognise this, and free up the medium-sized-object heap when an allocation fails (if that is really what's happening). Don't you agree?

Comment: @TonyK: right, I agree that once it cannot allocate from the available memory, it should try to reuse the memory that was freed in the current process in different buckets. The comment was more on whether that can be considered *fragmentation* or not. Obviously something is wrong if you have 1G of contiguous free ram and you cannot allocate 1M!!!

Comment: @David: Look at the code again. It allocates 1024 one-megabyte buffers at the end, not just 1.

Comment: @TonyK, I was not precise enough, but there is a single allocation that is failing, and when that allocation is failing there is still around 1G of contiguous memory (from what I understood in the question), but that is just a detail.

Comment: @David: No, that's not what happens if you run the code. Most of the 1GB is successfully allocated in the second pass.

Answer (score 1):

Using your code I performed your test and got the same result. I suspect that David Rodríguez is right in this case.

I ran the test and had the same result as you. It seems there might be this "bucket" behaviour going on.

I tried two different tests too. Instead of allocating 1GB of data using 1MB buffers I allocated the same way as the memory was first allocated after deleting. The second test I allocated the half meg buffer cleaned up then allocated the quater meg buffer, adding up to 512MB for each. Both tests had the same memory result in the end, only 512 is allocated an no large chunk of reserved memory.

As David mentions, most applications tend to make allocation of the same size. One can see quite clearly why this could be a problem though.

Perhaps the solution to this is that if you are allocating many smaller objects in this way you would be better to allocate a large block of memory and manage it yourself. Then when you're done free the large block.

Answer (score 1):

I spoke with some authorities on the subject (Greg, if you're out there, say hi ;D) and can confirm that what David is saying is basically right.

As the heap grows in the first pass of allocating ~0.25MB objects, the heap is reserving and committing memory.  As the heap shrinks in the delete pass, it decommits at some pace but does not necessarily release the virtual address ranges it reserved in the allocation pass.  In the last allocation pass, the 1MB allocations are bypassing the heap due to their size and thus begin to compete with the heap for VA.

**Note** that the heap is *reserving* the VA, not keeping it committed.  [VirtualAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366887%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [VirtualFree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366892%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) can help explain the different if you're curious.  This fact doesn't solve the problem you ran into, which is that the process ran out of [virtual address space](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366912%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This is a side-effect of the Low-Fragmentation Heap.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366750(v=vs.85).aspx

You should try disabling it to see if that helps. Run against both GetProcessHeap and the CRT heap (and any other heaps you may have created).